# Wi-Fi connection problem(Too Slow!) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, connection, error-handling

I have Asus-n552vw laptop that Ubuntu 16.04 installed upon. I have Wi-Fi problem. It only works to open 4 to 5 websites, then slow downs, and I must do disconnect and connect again. then I can open some sites and again slow downs! 
Also I think after some minutes it will be good and I can open web sites but after some minutes it goes down again!

I have other computers and smartphones in this network. all work good else this laptop(in Ubuntu i mean)!

This is the result of: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6: I edited it

Comment: Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) after such a drop in network throughput (download the script in advance) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.